# XML Edit to file using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xelement

I am working on a WPF application and I have a simple XML file that I am parsing using 'XmlDocument' and is working fine for the readinh part.
I want the use to be able to add, edit or delete any node and save these changes to the file.

I tried using 'XElement' but it seems to change the instance itself and not the file.

My XML file looks something like this:

```
<Configuration>
    <A_0.04_5>
        <ML407Configuration>
            <AM_Amp>10</AM_Amp>
            <AMRJ_Amp>10</AMRJ_Amp>
            <FM_Freq>20</FM_Freq>
            <FM_Phase_Shift>20</FM_Phase_Shift>
        </ML407Configuration>
        <BertConfiguration>
            <BERT_LR>25.78125</BERT_LR>
            <BERT_PRBS>7</BERT_PRBS>
            <BERT_Scaling>1000</BERT_Scaling>
        </BertConfiguration>
    </A_0.04_5>
    <B_1.333_0.15>
        <ML407Configuration>
            <AM_Amp>10</AM_Amp>
            <AMRJ_Amp>10</AMRJ_Amp>
            <FM_Freq>20</FM_Freq>
            <FM_Phase_Shift>20</FM_Phase_Shift>
        </ML407Configuration>
        <BertConfiguration>
            <BERT_LR>25.78125</BERT_LR>
            <BERT_PRBS>7</BERT_PRBS>
        </BertConfiguration>
    </B_1.333_0.15>

    <C_4_0.05>
        <ML407Configuration>
            <BUJ_LR>25</BUJ_LR>
            <BUJ_Pattern>7</BUJ_Pattern>
            <PM_BUJ_Amp>7</PM_BUJ_Amp>
            <BUJ_Amp>80</BUJ_Amp>
            </ML407Configuration>
        <BertConfiguration>
            <BERT_LR>25.78125</BERT_LR>
            <BERT_PRBS>7</BERT_PRBS>
        </BertConfiguration>
    </C_4_0.05> 
</Configuration>
```

What I tried is the following:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+"/Configuration.xml";
XElement xml = XElement.Load(filePath);
// This seems to remove the node from xml instance and not from the file
// Should I save the file again or is there another way to do it
// Same applies for add and edit
xml.Elements("C_4_0.05").Remove();
```

I have seen a lot of similar questions but I don't know if any of them change directly to the file or not

Comment: yes, you need to save the file after edit, ``xml.Save(filePath );``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XElement.Load`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.load) loads an XML structure from a file into memory. Any changes you make to that structure are also done in memory. If you want to write those changes back to a file (technically called [serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/)) you need to call [`XElement.Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.save).